# Sass Background Image mixin

Tags: css, haml, sass, compass-sass

I'm kind of new to Sass, but I'm attempting to create a workflow for myself. I generate "color packs" for my theme designs and need to specify the following variables for my mixin. Is there a better way to do this?:

```
// folder,filename,extension,repeat,x-pos,y-pos
@mixin background ($folder:style1, $img:file, $type:png, $repeat:no-repeat, $x:0, $y:0) {
    background-image: url(./images/#{$folder}/#{$img}.#{$type});
    background-repeat: #{$repeat};
    background-position: #{$x}px #{$y}px;
}
```

I'm inserting like so:

```
#nav {
  @include background(style2,myimage,png,repeat-x,10,10);
}
```

which yields this:

```
#nav {
  background-image: url(./images/style2/myimage.png);
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  background-position: 10px 10px;
}
```

I'd prefer to use CSS shorthand when possible, but I ran into errors with the output. I'd appreciate any expert advice if this is not the best way to do it.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

depending on how your packs are structured/applied you might be able to use a loop to generate a bunch of generic styles. See the documentation here: http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#id35

Do you really need 3 separate components to get your image url? wouldn't: `$img` and then setting that to `/folder/img.ext` be far easier?

Also, you don't need the `#{}` for repeat by the way.

I hope this is what you're after… the question is not very specific in terms of what you need the outcome to actually be.

Cheers,
Jannis

**Update:**

Okay, I see you've updated your question (thanks for that). I believe this could be a little better for general use:

```
@mixin background($imgpath,$position:0 0,$repeat: no-repeat) {
    background: {
        image: url($imgpath);
        position: $position;
        repeat: $repeat;
    }
}
.testing {
    @include background('/my/img/path.png');
}
```

This will then output:

```
.testing {
  background-image: url("/my/img/path.png");
  background-position: 0 0;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Or you can use the shorthand version:

```
@mixin backgroundShorthand($imgpath,$position:0 0,$repeat: no-repeat) {
    background: transparent url(#{$imgpath}) $repeat $position;
}
.testing2 {
    @include backgroundShorthand('/my/img/path.png');
}
```

Which will generate:

```
.testing2 {
  background: transparent url(/my/img/path.png) no-repeat 0 0;
}
```

Lastly *if you want to specify your base path to your image directory separately* you can do the following:

```
$imagedir:'/static/images/'; // define the base path before the mixin

@mixin backgroundShorthandWithExternalVar($filename,$position:0 0,$repeat: no-repeat) {
    background: transparent url(#{$imagedir}#{$filename}) $repeat $position;
}
.testing3 {
    @include backgroundShorthandWithExternalVar('filename.png');
}
```

This will then generate:

```
.testing3 {
  background: transparent url(/static/images/filename.png) no-repeat 0 0;
}
```

Is this what you needed?

If not feel free to update the question or reply/comment.

Comment: it makes no sense that your SASS code is longer than what it would be if it was to be written only with CSS...the only thing you need a mixin for is the URL part probably, not the rest. make your mixin names shorter.

Answer (score 4):

some other sample:

**path to the image:**

```
$path--rel      : "../images";
```

**color**

```
$black: #000000;
```

**creating the mixin:**

```
@mixin background-image($img, $background-position, $background-color) {
    background-image: url('#{$path--rel}/#{$img}');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: $background-position;
    background-color: $background-color ;
}
```

**using the mixing:**

```
.navbar-inverse {
  @include background-image("header.png", right, $black); 
}
```

**result:**

```
.navbar-inverse {
  background-image: url("../images/header.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: right;
  background-color: #000000;
}
```

Comment: hey, any comments on how the background-position like "right center" will work/ used.

Answer (score 3):

take one $var and it will make it easier for you.

```
$list: pranav shah

=author-images
  @each $author in $list
.photo-#{$author}
  background: image-url("avatars/#{$author}.png") no-repeat

   .author-bio
+author-images
```

css

```
.author-bio .photo-adam {
 background: url('/images/avatars/adam.png') no-repeat;
 }
.author-bio .photo-john {
 background: url('/images/avatars/john.png') no-repeat;
 }
.author-bio .photo-wynn {
 background: url('/images/avatars/wynn.png') no-repeat;
 }
.author-bio .photo-mason {
 background: url('/images/avatars/mason.png') no-repeat;
 }
.author-bio .photo-kuroir {
background: url('/images/avatars/kuroir.png') no-repeat;
}
```